# Why was my topic deleted?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

I created a topic (because there was a topic request) about using Realm in Android. But now it has been deleted.

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/4195/using-realm-in-android

For what reasons my topic has been deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go back to the draft and look through the edit history you will see the [edit to delete that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/59845). It appears there reasoning for doing so is because the topic exist elsewhere:

> Handling improvement requests. Realm topic already exists: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/3187/realm

Of course your example has some more information, a better edit would of been to merge that into the Realm topic in that section.

Comment: TL;DR: because documentation for a library/framework should have its own docs.